# Getting the max value of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe with indexes names of countries and columns medals.
I want to get the name of the country with the most number of gold medals.
I've tried this :

```
def answer_one():
    x= df[df['Gold.2']==df['Gold.2'].max()]
    return x.index
answer_one()
```

I want to get just the string which is the name of the country but instead I keep getting this

```
Index(['United States'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def answer_one():
    x= df[df['Gold.2']==df['Gold.2'].max()]
    return x.index.values[0]
answer_one()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want the concrete value, I would use the following code:

```
def answer_one():
    x= df[df['Gold.2']==df['Gold.2'].max()]
    return x.index.values[0]
answer_one()
```

This will return the first max country. If you want an array of all max countries:

```
def answer_one():
    x= df[df['Gold.2']==df['Gold.2'].max()]
    return x.index.values
answer_one()
```